# Why is the output "undefined" when i=10, for (i=0; i<10; i++)?

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I'm currently learning Javascript, less than a week after the final of my C++-centric programming class, and in `C++` the loop would stop when `i!<10` but I'm assuming it keeps on going in JS since I'm getting output after 9.

I'm using the JS console in Chrome

the code and output is:

```
for (i=0; i<10; i++){
console.log("This is the number" + i.toString());
}

This is the number0
This is the number1
This is the number2
This is the number3
This is the number4
This is the number5
This is the number6
This is the number7
This is the number8
This is the number9
undefined
```

Comment: Can you show us the code you're using?

Comment: The code in your title has no output. If you want people to answer your question you're going to have to provide the actual code you're having difficulty with.

Comment: exactly what you see above, I'm messing around in the Chrome JS console

Comment: If you want real help, you'll have to provide real code (with real context).  That garbage in your title isn't going to cut it... Not to mention there should be **no output** from the code in the title.

Comment: `undefined` is written to the console when code completes in chrome unless you return a value, use an expression, or write to the console.

Comment: your last edit isn't helpful either. show us what is inside your for loop (in the curly braces): `for (i=0;i<10;i++) { .... }`

Comment: Please don't put your code in the title of the question. Make your question specific, but keep the details in the body of the question. This question is more suited to a chat room than SO.

Comment: There's no need for tags in the title. Please read http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19190/147072 for more information.

Answer (score 3):

The undefined is for you don`t return anything when you run this code you have not any returned value and console evaluate your code and show return value after run it.. in runtime you write outputs like

```
This is the number0
This is the number1
.
.
This is the number9
```

and after that

**Console write return value of your code** that here is **undefined**

Answer (score 1):

The final `undefined` is the returned value of the `for` loop - it has no return value. When you type something into the console, its result is printed. And like I said, the result of a `for` loop is `undefined`.

Try putting this in the console:

```
var a = "asdf";
```

It should print `undefined`. But when you type:

```
a
```

It should print `"asdf"`. That's because the return value of a `var` statement is nothing.

Comment: Weird behaviour, it would confuse me too. A for loop never returns anything, it just runs code.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
for(var i = 0;i < 10;i++){ /*your stuff here*/ }
```

add `var` before variable `i`

Comment: Won't make a difference here - there is no ReferenceError; and it doesn't explain the "undefined".

Answer (score 0):

Below is the correct way and C++ and Javascript are similare, there should be something wrong with your code:

```
for (i=0; i<10; i++){
  console.log(i);
}
```

This is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cJyT8/)

[image]

Comment: Where did the "undefined" go, and why? That's what the question is about :)

Answer (score 0):

The returned value appears immediately after your results in Chrome's JS Console, just like node.js interactive mode, and many other modern JavaScript consoles. You should ignore the final undefined as it does not pertain to your loop, it is stopping at 9. If you don't believe me, try it in an HTML file instead of the console.

Some notes: You should always prepend var to any undefined variable before using it. In your example you use i without defining it first. If you do this, then the variable will be in the global namespace and possibly overwrite another instance of i in another context or class. An example:

```
function foo() {
    console.log(i);    // i => window.i
}

function bar() {
    var i = 0;         // i => window.bar.i
    console.log(i);
}

for (i=0; i<10; i++) { // loop is using window.i because no var declaration
    console.log(i);    // will log 0 to 9
}

foo();  // will log 9
bar();  // will log 0
```